# Form change event

Tags: javascript, forms, dojo

I am trying to have a button change CSS class from 'active' to 'inactive' based on whether the form is valid or not

So I have this declarative bit...

```
<form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="myForm" action="http://somthing">
<script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="change" data-dojo-args="e">
// for some reason change returns dom object not dijit object....
var self = dijit.byId( this.id);
require( [ 'dojo/dom-class' ], function (domClass) {
    var tmp, on = 'active' , off = 'inactive';
    if (self.get('state')) {
        // invalid
        tmp = off; off=on; on=tmp;
    }
domClass.replace( 'complete', on, off);
});
</script>
..rest of form and submit button with id='complete' is here.
```

This script is intended to changes the class of a submit button depending on whether the form isvalid or not. My first question is why is this routine getting the DOM object as `this` instead of the Dijit object, as the examples seem to imply I should be getting the latter. My second question is whether I should be doing this in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `target` property of the event you received: you're most likely receiving it off the form, *bubbled* (via HTML event bubbling) up from an actual control in your form.  It's a native DOM event rather than a higher-level Dojo event, hence `this`  being the DOM node.

It's sometimes easier to use a plain old piece of JavaScript code instead of a `dojo/on` script, and use `dojo/on` to subscribe manually.  There's no magic, and you can see exactly what you're subscribing to then:

```
require(['dojo/on'], function (on) {
  var myForm = dijit.byId("myForm");
  on(form, "change", function(evt) {
    // Handle the event here, referring to myForm rather than trying to
    // work with 'this'.
  });
});
```

More examples, including checking for validity, are at: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/Form.html#using-native-form-elements

Comment: Yes, I get the impression that I sometimes try and swallow the whole Dojo philosophy hook line and sinker, when there is probably an easier way. From the examples, I expected to get the higher level event though. For example, the page you gave captures a `submit` event rhrough `dojo/on` and appears to expect `this` to be the Dojo object, not the DOM object, calling `this.validate()`

Comment: My team and I never use the dojo/on <script> tag support, and work on keeping the HTML and JS totally separate.  That gives us the really big win with Dojo: separation of presentation from logic, and componentizing and reuse.

Comment: Btw, the page I link to subscribes to a _method_ `onSubmit`, which isn't the same as a DOM event.  It uses a `dojo/method` script thing (which is really a call into `dojo/aspect`) to hook into `onSubmit`, which is on the Dojo `Form` widget, not an HTML `form` DOM node.  Keep a good separation between what's a Dojo widget object and what's a DOM node, and you're sorted.  (Broken and weeping inside, sure, but sorted...)

Comment: Nope, look at the "validate" example, not the "using native form elements" example, the first uses `dojo/on` in exactly the manner I described.
I agree with your _separating presentation from logic_ comment - this is a hack to fix someone else's dirty laundry and whilst personally I would put this in something like a page controller file, or extend a Dijit class to do something like this, those option weren't really on the cards this time round.